# How to proper debug errors in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

For example, I have the following code in my template

```
<button class="btn btn-blue" type="submit"  {{action 'verify' model.model}}>Continue</button>
```

And such action doesn't exist in my controller/component. When I click the button - nothing happens, I see no errors in browser console.

How to catch such errors? Maybe some config option?

Comment: I am sure, in developement mode you will get assertion error. like `Nothing handled the action 'verify'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.`

Comment: My question was a little different. I.e. why i get no console errors, like "Sorry but action verify doesn't exist" - that would help troubleshoot the problem. I'm running ember: ember serve --environment local, maybe I need to adjust something in config?

Comment: try this `ember s --environment=development` . Do you have any environment specified for `local` ? if possible  update your `config/environment.js` file content

Comment: I need local environment so I can load and work against local API SDK generated with swagger. Development environment is using different npm packange and work with remote api, while I need localhost apil. Is there a way I need to define in my config file?

Comment: In production mode assertion error code stripped from source code, but in development mode it will throw assertion errors. I am not aware of  stuff you are working on. please read this [debugging guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/configuring-ember/debugging/) page and include corresponding configuration. and also make sure you haven't given any empty implementation for Global error handling functions like `Ember.onerror` and `Ember.RSVP.on('error', function(error) {}` and `Ember.Logger.error`